# Where to start my idea for creating a game using python?

Tags: python

I have been studying and using Python for the last couple of months, I have an idea for a game, a simple game for mobiles and I don't know where to start from here?

I know that this is a little vague and fuzzy, but any answer would be appreciated.

A few more questions:
Do I need to install something, or the notepad and the cmd are enough?
If I do, which one do you advise?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your goal is perfectly laudable, but unfortunately the SO framework isn't a good place to answer vague open-ended questions.  On the bright side, when you're actually developing your game, SO could very well be a good place to bring concrete and specific questions about difficulties you're encountering.  Good luck!

Comment: Open-ended questions like these are abundant on a site like Quora. Try there first. And as @DSM pointed out, you're always welcome on StackOverflow to discuss technical issues. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended Python library for writing games is `pygame` for 2d games, and I use `Panda3d` and `PyOpenGL` for 3d games (the last two are a bit difficult to learn). But I think all the three aren't supported on mobile devices, they were created for desktop game programming. For mobile game creating you would use `Java` (Android) or `Objective-C` (iOS), or an game engine like `Unity`.

So think about it, do you really want to make it running on mobile devices, you should switch the programming language, or you decide to develop desktop games, which are in my opinion easier to share with the people you know.

Comment: what do you mean easier to share?

Comment: If you're going to distribute a finished game (to friends ect.), you can send the desktop games compiled as `.exe` or as pure Python code via email or put the files on a webserver. You can do this with an mobile app too (`.apk` on Android), but the person won't be able to install the app correctly in most cases (You need to set some developer options ect).

Comment: what about frameworks like kivy and such?

Comment: @Gonzalo I've never used Kivy, but I thought it's for GUI programming...